# WCF JSON object

Tags: jquery, wcf

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public MyEmployee DoWorksINGLE()
    {

            return new MyEmployee("Bad", "Munner");


    }
 [DataContract]
    public class MyEmployee
    {
        public string FirstName = "";
        public string LastName = "";
        public MyEmployee(string F, string L)
        {
            FirstName = F;
            LastName = L;
        }
    }
```

I get following out put.

{"d":{"__type":"MyService.MyEmployee:#efleet"}}

Only the name of object not the values.
can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the JSON serializer only works against properties and not fields and they need to be marked with the `DataMember` attribute.  Try converting the FirstName and LastName fields to properties and see if that fixes the problem.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEmployee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: if i want to return a list of object of Entity Framework type.